# Hierarchical select hook form alter

Tags: 7, forms, taxonomy-terms

I have a problem with getting my `module_form_alter` to work for hierarchical select. I am running on *Drupal 7* and my content type is called *mytemp* and I'm pretty sure my form-id is *mytemp_node_form*. I have a taxonomy called *ICA* which my hierarchical select references to.

I get the following error when I run it:

> *Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in arjmod_form_alter() (line 8 of /var/www/hcms/sites/all/modules/arjmod/arjmod.module)*

I would like to have my hierarchical select appear with a fixed row height but I can't get it to work.

This is my code:

```
<?php 
function mymodule_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == 'mytemp_node_form'){
    foreach ($form['taxonomy'] as &$vocab)
      if($vocab['#type'] == 'hierarchical_select')
        $vocab['#size'] = 10;
}} ?>
```

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: I just used hierarchical select in a custom form the other week. Why are you using a form alter on a node form? Why not just configure the field's widget settings using the hierarchical select widget? Do you have the hierarchical select's taxonomy submodule enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `$form['taxonomy']` is not an array.

There are some options for hierarchical selects maybe this is all you need:

`http://localhost/admin/config/content/hierarchical_select`

Comment: Thanks man, i'll check it out and update the post if i get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to assign taxonomy to a variable, and $vocab shouldn't be passed byref:

```
$taxonomy = $form['taxonomy'];
foreach ($taxonomy as $vocab) {...}
```